# SonarQube Quality Gate passes even after project have Issue

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops

For a newly Created project in SonarQube, report is showing Reliability Rating as E but still it is passing the Project.

I am using default Quality Gate.

I understand the conditions in the quality gate is defined on new code but as it is a new project then first time the report generated into SonarQube should be considered new code only, but it didn't happened.

Can I get some help to explain/solve this.

Project Metrics:
[image: Project Metrics]

Quality Gate:
[image: Quality Gate]

Answer (score 0):

An initial analysis is never considered new code. As per [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/new-code-period/#header-2):

> You can define New Code as changes from a previous version, a specific analysis, a reference branch, or within a specific period (number of days)

Initial analysis is considered baseline since when *new code* can be counted. Default quality gate only sets goals for new code and as such it cannot trigger on an initial (baseline) analysis.

Comment: So is there any way we can check quality gate condition on baseline?

Comment: You can define a quality gate with conditions on overall code instead of new code.